# How can I select vertical data from a details table horizontally using sql query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

it is possible that similar questions have been asked earlier, but I can't find them. So here is my objective.
I have three tables like `1.Bill 2.BillDetail 3.ExpenseInfo`. Table "Bill" have a primary key named "`BillID`" which is foreign key of table "BillDetail". Similarly, table "ExpenseInfo" have a PK "`ExpenseID`" which is also FK to "BillDetail". Data kept in these tables are in below format. `For 1 entry in Bill table, there might be 1 or more rows in BillDetail table where each row contains 1 ExpenseID`. Now I want to write a query which will select data something like-

```
BillID BillDate Fuel Food Travel
  1    28-02-12  10   20    50
```

here Fuel, Food, Travel are various expense types saved in table "ExpenseInfo". I have tried below. Am I going the right way or some other smart way exists to do this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_BillInfoDetail a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
SELECT ISNULL(ExpenseID,0) AS ExpenseID, ISNULL(ExpenseName,'N/A') AS ExpenseName    
FROM t_expenseinfo 
WHERE ExpenseID=1 
) AS LocalTravel ON a.ExpenseID = LocalTravel.ExpenseID
```

Newly Added
Thank you all for your replies.
Currently I am doing as below for my purpose. Hope you like it.

```
SELECT 
BI.* , BID.ExpenseID, BID.BillDescription, BID.LocalTravel, BID.LocalHotel, BID.Fuel  
FROM  
(
SELECT * 
FROM t_BillInfo 
WHERE BillID = 1 
) AS BI 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
SELECT BillID, BillDescription, ExpenseID, 
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE ExpenseID WHEN 1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END), 0) AS LocalTravel,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE ExpenseID WHEN 2 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END), 0) AS LocalHotel,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE ExpenseID WHEN 3 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END), 0) AS Fuel  
FROM t_BillInfoDetail 
GROUP BY BillID, BillDescription, ExpenseID  
) AS BID ON BI.BillID = BID.BillID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably I'm not getting the question right, but as I see it you have 3 tables joined like a "chain" `Bill -HAS_MANY> BillDetail -HAS_ONE> ExpenseInfo`.

If that is the case you just have to join the tables with inner joins requesting the data from each of the tables you require. You didn't provide your table structure but should be done this way:

```
select b.aBillField, bd.aBillDetailField, ei.aExpenseInfoField from bill b
inner join billDetail bd
on b.billID = bd.billFK
inner join expenseInfo ei
on ei.expenseFK = bd.billDetailId
where expenseId = 1
```

Of course, replace the invented fields with the corresponding ones.

Answer (score 0):

In case if u need a store procedure,and if u can be more clear in your question we can easily answer you...for now you try this

```
  create procedure [dbo].[SP_GetInfo]
   (
    @ExpenseID int
   )
  as 
  begin
  select Bill .BillID , BillDetail .BillDate , ExpenseInfo.Fuel 
  from Bill , BillDetail , ExpenseInfo
  where Bill .BillID = BillDetail .BillID       
  AND ExpenseInfo.ExpenseID  =@ExpenseID
 GO
```

try this if u have any error please ask me....

Answer (score 0):

If I read correctly, you want to `PIVOT` your data in the ExpenseInfo table. Try the following:

```
SELECT BillID,
       BillDate,
       Fuel,
       Food,
       Travel
FROM   (SELECT BillID,
               BillDate,
               ExpenseName,
               ExpenseAmount
        FROM   Bill AS B
               INNER JOIN BillDetail BD
                 ON B.BillID = BD.BillID
               INNER JOIN ExpenseInfo EI
                 ON BD.ExpenseID = EI.ExpenseID) AS up PIVOT (SUM( ExpenseAmount
       ) FOR
       ExpenseName IN (Fuel, Food, Travel)) AS pvt
ORDER  BY BillID
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I could not check it as I am using MS SQL Server 2000 (Ent. Edition.)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using. It fulfills my requirement.

```
SELECT 
BI.* , BID.ExpenseID, BID.BillDescription, BID.LocalTravel, BID.LocalHotel, BID.Fuel  
FROM  
(
SELECT * 
FROM t_BillInfo 
WHERE BillID = 1 
) AS BI 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
SELECT BillID, BillDescription, ExpenseID, 
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE ExpenseID WHEN 1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END), 0) AS LocalTravel,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE ExpenseID WHEN 2 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END), 0) AS LocalHotel,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE ExpenseID WHEN 3 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END), 0) AS Fuel  
FROM t_BillInfoDetail 
GROUP BY BillID, BillDescription, ExpenseID  
) AS BID ON BI.BillID = BID.BillID
```